# Android Native C++ Errors

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am using Almalence: Open Camera repository

[Checkout the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbgWt.png)

Gives Compile Errors:

Error:(24, 34) ImageConversionUtils.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

make.exe: *** [C:\Users\sagar_000\Documents\OpenCamera-master\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/OpenCamera-master/C_\Users\sagar_000\Documents\OpenCamera-master\app\src\main\jni\bestshot\bestshot.o] Error 1

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\sagar_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Could you show the error from the console where the ``make`` process is running?

Comment: @StephenG - Do you mean from Gradle console ?

Comment: Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\sagar_000\Documents\OpenCamera-master\app\src\main\java\com\almalence\plugins\processing\hdr\HDRProcessingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. @StephenG

Comment: I have got some steps from the developer please it is not much clear to me how to implement with Android Studio

1. Create OpenCamera folder in android-source/packages/apps directory


2. Put attached Android.mk into this folder


3. Build OpenCamera in Eclipse and put the result APK to the same directory (rename the APK to OpenCamera.apk)
4. Extract lib folder from this OpenCamera.apk (using any zip archive tool) into the same directory

Comment: 5. At this point you should have 3 items in your android-source/packages/apps/OpenCamera directory:
OpenCamera.apk
Android.mk
lib


6. Now you need to add OpenCamera to build. To achieve it add OpenCamera to PRODUCT_PACKAGES variable assignment in android-source/build/target/product/core.mk


7. Build Android

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add these ndk properties into your build.gradle. Must be same level with defaultConfig

```
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' // This is not necessary unless you have precompiled libraries in your project.
}

task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
            '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
            'all',
            'NDK_DEBUG=1'
}

task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
    def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
            '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
            'clean'
}
```